# How can one connect to MySQL using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition on Mac with the Database Navigator plugin?

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc

I am following the 8.0 tutorial from MySQL and have downloaded a zip file containing the JDBC files and have unzipped them. I have added them to the classpath as the MySQL docs says to do (I made the changes to 'path' and 'ver'):

```
export CLASSPATH=/path/mysql-connector-java-ver.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

My IntelliJ does not have the necessary DB tools since those are only available in the Ultimate Edition. Therefore I am using the Database Navigator plugin.

I edited the *Driver Library* and *Driver* to connect to the jar file under *Settings*, but the sample code (all the imports are there) returns

```
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=root&password=password123$
```

I don't know if this matters but when I run the *Test Connection* button under Settings, everything works fine; connection is successful.

I am thinking it is the CLASSPATH above and I should place that into one of the various .something-file that I often see but I have no idea how to work with those.

Can someone advise on what to do or if there is any other editor/IDE that will let you learn how to integrate Java and MySQL without all this extra stuff?

Answer (score 0):

The error is gone. I had to manually add the jar file to the Project Structure (File/Project Structure). Just loading the jar file as I had done as described in my original question is not enough.

All this was probably under the IntelliJ documentation but I only found info for the Ultimate Edition.